# using the divergence theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Gauss Divergence Theorem to compute $$\int \int \limits_S F\cdot n \,dS$$ where $n$ is the outward normal for the following:

$S$ is the surface $x^2 +y^2=z^2$ and $z \in [0,1]$, and $F(x,y,z)=(x,xy,z)$

The $div(F)=2+x$. I let z be z and $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. If you sub these into the surface equation, it ends up as z=r so I made my limits be $r \in [0,z]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Then integrated $$\int \limits_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int \limits_{z=0}^1 \int \limits_{r=0}^z (2+r\cos\theta) r\,dr\,dz\,d\theta$$ and then got $2\pi/3$.

But in the solution, it was $2\pi/3-\pi$ which I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ is not a closed surface, so you need to include the integral over the part of the boundary the volume that is not part of $S$: in particular, in your case this is the disc $x^2+y^2<1$, $z=1$.

$F \cdot n$ is equal to (choosing the outward normal!) $z$, so it is constant and equal to $1$. Thus the surface integral is just the area of the disc, which is $\pi$. You subtract it because it should start off on the same side as the integral over the rest of the surface.

(Don't worry, everyone makes this mistake in vector calculus...)

Comment: So when do you know when it is closed or not? When there is only one normal? Because I can see that a cone has two normals since it has two surfaces.

Comment: No, the issue is that the volume you integrate over has two "faces": the one parametrised by the curved surface of the cone, and the flat one which is the disc I mention. The question asks for the integral over the curved bit, so you have to take into account the flat bit of the boundary to your volume.